# iPhone - UIScrollView to scroll programmatically with animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I'm using following code to scroll to a point in my scroll view:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

But its not animating the scroll to a point. Is there any way to scroll with animation?

Comment: Both methods `[scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];` and `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];` should animate your content with animation then maybe the issue is related to another point of your code. Can you post the init code for your scrollView?

Comment: are you calling this method from a thread that's not the main thread?

Comment: Thanks lomanf for the informatin. I changed to [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES] and it worked for me. I don't know what's the issue with setContentOffset.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your line of code in a method and have that get called by an NSTimer. Have it detect when it has reached the maximum offsets to know when to stop.